# How to include an external non-Android Eclipse library project into a Android-Studio project without copying/moving/editing?

Tags: java, android, gradle

How can i use an external, Ecliplse non-android-library-project in my project, without moving or copying or changing it? It is important that that library remains untouched because it is still being edited by others and other projects are referenced to it there aswell.

The library is in the same parent directory as my android studio project.

I did put these lines into my settings.gradle, without success.

```
include ':abc'
project(':abc').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../abc ')
```

This apparently works for library-projects which include gradle, but apparently not for libraries without gradle.

The result is this gradle sync error:

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath:' Could not resolve project :abc

Comment: I have files like these inside 'abc' though (if they are of any use):

.classpath
.project
build.properties
build.xml
cruise.xml
abc.xml

Comment: the author of the library just told me that it is a (non-android) eclipse library project.

Comment: Btw, the reason I don't want to move 'abc'-library from it's location is that it is being used by other projects aswell. Copying is not an option because the library is still being edited from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this... my conclusion so far: It is apparently not possible to use such a library (from Eclipse) without modifying those a little bit. I did these changes to get them working so far:

- inside the src directory, make the directories main/java/ and move the package with the source codes to there.
- write a build.gradle file in the root and define the module dependencies in it.
- move the AndroidManifest.xml into src/main/

Answer (score 0):

In the dependencies section in `build.gradle` of your app module, add below.

`implementation project(path:':abc' , configuration: 'default')`

And in `settings.gradle`, only `include ':abc'` should be enough.

Comment: by 'only', you mean to remove the line `project(':abc').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../abc ')`, right? I did that, but  I still get the same results.

Comment: are you sure with `path:':abc'`? Where do i tell that the library is located in the parent folder?

Comment: Yes, for your first question. Weird. Maybe you need to do `Clean Project` and `Rebuild Project` in the `Build` menu of Android Studio. `settings.gradle` is in the root of your project, so is `abc` module. So, there is no need to define a directory for it.

Comment: Clearn or Rebuild gives me the error: `Unable to find a matching configuration of project :abc: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.`. **my abc module is not in the root of my project! It is in the parent directory, so it is next to the project directory** Sorry, I did not write this clearly (I am edititing my post now).

Comment: when i click on "open file" next to the error message, I get navigated to the dependency{} block in app/build.gradle. My guess is, that AS is expecting a gradle-project but since it is a non-android-elicpse-library-project, there is no gradle. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: For the moment, i don't have a solution. Temporarily, you can get a compiled `.jar` file of the module and add it to your `app/libs` folder. But, since the abc module is live and still being edited; this isn't what you want.